# Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am retrieving data from database to `gridview` `textbox` there are two rows in database but not able to fetch it:

```
    string sr_no;
    int rowIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox5");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox6");
                TextBox box7 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox7");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("TextBox8");

                box1.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["RD_PS_APPLab_Parameter"].ToString();
                sr_no = dt1.Rows[i-1]["RD_SR_No"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["Test"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["Test_Condition"].ToString();
                box4.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["Method"].ToString();
                box5.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["CTQ"].ToString();
                box6.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["Specification_RD_PS_AppLab"].ToString();
                box7.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["UOM"].ToString();
                box8.Text = dt1.Rows[i-1]["Remarks"].ToString();
                rowIndex++;
            }
```

i am getting error

> Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection

Comment: Does your row have 9 cells? What have you researched to solve your problem?

Comment: Does your view have 1 more row than the row count? What's in row 0? What's creating the rows in the grid view anyway?

Comment: Yes each row have 9 cells

Comment: And the rest of my comment? Read [ask]

Comment: If I'm going to guess, `Gridview1` has less rows than `dt1`.  You need to step through this with a debugger and see where it throws the exception and investigate why.  There's nothing 'obvious' that's wrong.

Comment: loop moves for first time perfectly. but at second iteration it throws error.

Comment: Number of rows in `GridView1` and `dt1` are equal?

Comment: And **where** does it throw an exception? Just try debugging.

Comment: Gridview rows add on button click dynamically.. but after adding data through gridview. I m showing data in gridview at this time I m using this code.

Comment: i used debugger also to find error. Loop moves for first time perfectly. but at second iteration it throws error

Comment: @SadhanaBhor: It would be simpler to add data through the footerrow

Comment: data added in gridview perfectly.. its about showing data in gridview textbox which are dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

there is tow probability there

1) that your grid dose not have 8 cells

2)your `for loop`  is not correct 
instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
//...
}
```

try this

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
/..
}
```

Note, you should start the loop with 0 if your bussniss logic

so your for loop will be like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
    /..
    }
```

Comment: Why would it start from one?

Comment: i thought it is something from his logic :)

Comment: @daveL - The op references `dt1.Rows[i-1]`

Comment: As the question uses `i-1` everywhere, surely your amendment it going to cause the last row to be missed?  I appreciate it looks odd, but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: that snippet looks like a wrong way of doing `.DataBind()`. nothing more.

Comment: my bad. "Gridview rows add on button click dynamically.. but after adding data through gridview. I m showing data in gridview at this time I m using this code." it changes the whole question